# Proof of Lemma 6.1, II in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne's proof for Lemma 6.1, II, he said "it would be sufficient to show that there only finitely many prime divisors $Y$ of $U$ for which $v_Y(f) \neq 0$". How can we conclude that $v_Y(f) \neq 0$ for $Y$ is a prime divisor in $X$ if and only if $v_{Y'}(f) \neq 0$, with $Y' = Y \cap U$ ?

Comment: It may happen that $Y\cap U=\emptyset$ and $v_Y(f)\neq 0$. However, since he's assuming the scheme to be noetherian, it is a noetherian topological space, so there are only finitely many prime divisors of this kind. Now, if $Y\cap U=Y'\neq\emptyset$ the generic point of $Y$ is contained in $U$, so you can consider the valuation as coming from $U$.